# jQuery events fire more than once

Tags: jquery, ajax

first of all, I did my home work, I already searched Google and used `evt.stopPropagation();` and `unbind` method, but not fixing my problem... .

Here is my case:

Imagine I have a left sidebdar with some linkes, on click of each link the middle col will be reloaded by ajax with some code like this:

```
<script>
$('.leftsidebar a').on('click', function(){
    var page = $(this).attr('class')
    $('#middleCol').load('loader.php?page='+ page);
});
</script>
```

So on each click on the left side bar a tag, the middle col will loads that a tag `class`.php, it's just fine.

now in the pages that I'm loading in the middle col, at the end of the page I have some javascripts,, for example if it loads by `loader.php?page=test` in `test` page I have some new jQuery lines, an example:

```
<script>
$('#blah').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'server.php',
        success: function(response){
            //blah  
        }   
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Now the problem is, when the first time, I load test page by clicking on leftside bar a tag, it works just fine, on click of `#blah` only 1 request will be sent to `server.php`, but when I click on another `a` from leftsidebar, then come back to the `test`, now if I click on `blah`, the ajax request will be sent twice to the `server.php`, and so on..., if I try it again, request will be sent for 3 times!

How can I prevent such behavior? what is the solution?

I appreciate helps.

Comment: Interesting. Are you re-binding the click event on each load of new data?

Comment: What does `loader.php` contains? Does it contains another JavaScript lines on it?

Comment: @Steve the answer is no, it just does smth like include_once('page')

Comment: @ tymeJV It seems I am since the new js codes are in the newly loaded page

Comment: @behz4d but that `include` is going to include a page with Javascript codes, right?

Comment: @Does your included page contains HTML headers too?

Comment: @steve no, just some divs which will be placed in the main page middle col

Comment: I've replied you in an answer. You should not be including Javascript in any file apart from the parent one. (layout)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do that too if no more than one click handler is bounded to this element:

```
$('#blah').off('click').on('click', function(){...});
```

But better would be to not include useless/redundant code

Comment: how about if I'm using `$(document).on('click', '.edit_history', function(){`? how I should add off('click') to this?

Comment: `$(document).off('click', '.edit_history').on('click', '.edit_history', function(){...});`

Comment: this has stopped the click event on the `blah`!

Comment: sorry, you mean: $(document).off('click', '.edit_history')  as stopped #blah click to work?

Comment: the same results, it prevents the event to even fire once

Answer (score 3):

A fairly simple solution would be to bind data to `#blah` to determine whether that click event is already bound to prevent it from binding again.

```
$("#blah:not([data-bound])").on('click', function () {
    /* your code */
});
//not using .data to ensure attribute string set for selector use.
$("#blah").attr('data-bound', 'bound');
```

Comment: in this case, the next time I click on `blah` nothing would happen, and that's wrong, it needs to fire only once.

Comment: @behz4d that shouldn't be the case; the event never gets unbound.  Do you want it to be?

Comment: This is a pretty nice suggestion, but I believe :not() syntax is only supported IE9 and up, so just something to think about.

Comment: I'm using the `blah` like `$(document).on('click', '.del_comment', function(){`, how I'm supposed to add your solution to this?

Comment: @behz4d that changes the question somewhat; are there *multiple* `.del_comment`s on the page that are remaining on the page even after it gets reloaded?  In that case you shouldn't load that script asynchronously; you only need it to be there once

Comment: yes, one of the pages is comments, each comment has a `.del_comment` which is used to delete the comment

Answer (score 2):

You should separate your `js` files from the views including them in the header of the site:

```
<script src="yourPath/actions.js"></script>
```

This is usually the correct way to do it.

Include the file only ONCE in the parent `.php` file and get rid of mistakes like the one you are having.

Your `loader.php` should not include any Javascript code. There's no need.

Comment: the reason I did this is because the left side bar contains more than 30 a links, in each page I may have 20KB of js codes, this will cause my main page to be more than 600KB!

Comment: <<Your loader.php should not include any Javascript code. There's no need.>>  exactly!

Comment: @behz4d I still not understanding how do you calculate those KBs and why are they related with the link tag, which is only text.

Answer (score 1):

Each time your `sidebar` ajax fires, it **adds** a script to the page, which **adds** a click event to `#blah`.  So when `#blah` is clicked, it is firing *each* of those handlers.

You can either override the click event each time by assigning the onclick handler using plain old javascript `document.getElementById('blah').onclick = yourClickFunction` or you can first turn off the click events, then add a new one with jquery

`$('#blah').off('click').on('click', yourFunction);`

Another suggestion is to use event delegation for your sidebar links, so instead of this:
`$('.leftsidebar a').on('click', function(){`
do this:
`$('.leftsidebar').on('click', 'a', function(){`

This creates a single handler for all 40 or so of those links, which is a bit more efficient.  Plus any links that get added later will automatically have the click handler, without you needing to attach it.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you're loading your inner page you are rebinding `blah` click event.
Try moving your blah click to your outter script.

Comment: that's why I'm using ajax, left sidebar contains more than 30 links, in that way my main page could be 400KB or even more..

Comment: ah, ok, well my identification of the problem is correct, but to solve the issue you may want to go with one of the other suggestions.